# How to get time 2 hours earlier using Calendar API?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to get my start date and time as todays date and time should be 00:00 but end time should be current hour - 2. With me below code, I am not able to understand how to get end time as current hour - 2.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());

System.out.println(startTime);
System.out.println(endTime);
```

If I run the above code just now, this is what gets printed out :

```
2015/08/17 00:00
2015/08/17 12:00
```

But I want to have end time as 10:00 which is 2 hours earlier than noon time so it should print this:

```
2015/08/17 00:00
2015/08/17 10:00
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I have tried:

```
    Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    endDate.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2);

    String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
    String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());

    System.out.println(startTime);
    System.out.println(endTime);
```

And this is what it is printing out:

```
2015/08/17 12:00
2015/08/17 10:53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Calendar`'s `add(int field, int amount)` method to add a negative number of hours. Like so:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2);
```

[Link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))

Comment: Thanks for the help but with this my startTime is getting changed as well along with endTime. My startTime should be exactly whatever it is right now.

Comment: May be because you're cloning your startDate. Why not create a new Calendar instance for your endDate?

Comment: sure, I tried that but still startTime is getting messed up. I have updated the question with details.

Comment: Make sure you're setting the Hours and Minutes as before, and to each Calendar object.